# Constrain the range of a parametric type to integer values

Tags: julia

I've created a parametrized type where the parameter is an integer. Below is a reasonable MWE.

```
struct InverseTaylor{N}
    a::Vector{Float64}
    function InverseTaylor{N}() where {N}
        a = something_done_with_n(N)
        new(a)
    end
end
```

But I'm unhappy to have the `where {N}` not constraining the `N` further.

What I could think of during writing this question is to add a verification in the inner constructor, like so:

```
N isa Int || error("$N should be an integer")
```

Yet it still feels like there should be a better way.

P.S. I know there are caveats to using types parameterized on integer values, but I feel like if the language allows for the concept, there should also be a way to make it clear what I expect from `N` in the struct definition.

Comment: You cannot really encode this in the type domain, but you can in the constructor. You could, for example, require that `something_done_with_n` only accepts integers.

Answer (score 0):

would

```
struct InverseTaylor{N}
    a::Vector{Float64}
    function InverseTaylor{N}() where N <: Integer
        a = something_done_with_n(N)
        new(a)
    end
end
```

work for what you want to do?

Comment: That's a subtype relationship, which is the wrong kind. `N` is probably 2, for example, not `Int64`. `2 <: Integer` is `false`, while `2 isa Integer` is `true`.

Comment: Ah, I see. The best I come up with in that case would be adding an assertion such as `@assert N isa Integer` to the function then.

Comment: That assertion is what I've done in the line of code towards the bottom of my post. Except that I use `cond || error()` because Julia assertions can be disabled and are in fact disabled by default.

Comment: I think that using @assert for an error thrown when the programmer has made an error is something that one ___should__ be able to turn off. Input errors coming outside the programmer's control such as from the user need to throw such a non-eliminable error() though.